# on submit click button hide first tab and show next tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we having three tabs initially first tabs should enabled i's working fine. after click submit button second tab should be open but it's is not working.

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav" role="tablist" id="myLinks">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="home">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="menu2">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section>


    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myTabs form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkHref = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
        $('#myLinks li')
              .find('a[href="#' + linkHref + '"]')
          .parent()
          .next()
          .find('a').tab('show')
          .attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
    });
</script>
```

[Pass the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1HW0.png)

in this picture value pass to the `linkHref` but after click submit button hide the first tab but next tab is not opening ..

[Second Image blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s9AC.png)

second screen shot blank page after enter submit button

Comment: @IvinRaj Your code is working fine, check the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7baqxro0/

Comment: http://demo.medeil.com/css/main.css  @MehulJariwala

Comment: @Shiladitya yes sir working fine thanks

Comment: your code work properly.

Comment: sir can you add css code and jquery version code please @Shiladitya

Comment: try change `.parents('.tab-pane')` to `.closest('.tab-pane')`, and you don't need that `.attr('data-toggle', 'tab');` line as it already is.

Comment: sir how to disabled remaing tab before submit button@Shiladitya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7baqxro0/1/

```js
$("#myTabs form").on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var linkHref = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
  $('#myLinks li a').removeClass('active');
  $('#myLinks li')
    .find('a[href="#' + linkHref + '"]')
    .parent()
    .next()
    .find('a')
    .tab('show')
    .addClass('active')
    .attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
    
  $('a.nav-link').not('.active').css('pointer-events', 'none');
});

$('a.nav-link').not('.active').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myLinks">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="home">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="menu2">
                        <form id="form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section>


    </div>
</div>
```

Please add your `CSS` to the code, intentionally I skipped it.

I've used `CSS` property `pointer-events: none` instead of disabled.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

working: **https://jsfiddle.net/q6adcnLs/**

1. you have multiple elements with same `id` attribute
2. you've misplaced `.active` class to `.nav-link` (which should be in the `.nav-item`)
3. you can use `return true` or `return false` instead of `preventDefault()`

**UPDATE:**

disable other inactive tabs **https://jsfiddle.net/q6adcnLs/1/**